# Vertical scrollbars in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to ensure this page shows with as `100%` height and width, but upon doing so, as shown in the code, scrollbars appear.

In Chrome, the behaviour is different and is as expected. It seems like it should be fairly simple to deal with, but I can't seem to get it working.

To replicate the issue, simply run this code in IE.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,700');
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;

}


body {
    background: #F1F1F1 url('http://via.placeholder.com/1900');
    background-size: cover;
}

.main-bg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -9999;
}

.main-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 500px;
}

.large-only,
.small-only,
.tiny-only {
    display: none;
}

.text-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text-container-parent {
    position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    .large-only {
        display: block;
    }
    .text-container-parent {
        width: 55%;
    }
    .text-container {
        padding-bottom: 8vh;
    }
    .text-word.massive {
        font-size: 5.2vw;
        letter-spacing: -5px;
    }
    body {
        font-size: 1.68vw;
    }
    .button-div {
        padding-top: 2.6vw;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 721px) and (max-width: 1279px) {
    .small-only {
        display: block;
    }
    .text-container-parent {
        width: 80%;
    }
    .text-word.massive {
        letter-spacing: -2px;
        font-size: 7vw;
    }
    body {
        font-size: 2.5vw;
    }
    .button-div {
        padding-top: 3.5vw;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    .tiny-only {
        display: block;
    }
    .text-container-parent {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .text-word.massive {
        letter-spacing: -2px;
        font-size: 12.2vw;
    }
    body {
        font-size: 3.5vw;
    }
    .button-div {
        padding-top: 6.1vw;
    }
    .text-container {
        position: static;
        transform: none!important;
        margin: auto;
        padding-top: 2em;
    }
    .title-row {
        margin: auto;
    }
    .button-div {
        margin: auto;
    }
    .logo-and-title {
        margin: auto;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .main-container {
        height: 100%!important;
        width: 100%!important;
        margin: auto!important;
        min-width: inherit!important;
    }
    body {
        background: #F1F1F1;
    }

    .main-bg {
        min-width: inherit!important;
        width: 100%;
        }
}

.text-container-parent {
    height: 100%;
}

.no-select {
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

.no-select-buttons {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

img.logo-large {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 32vh;
    max-height: 32vh;
    text-align: center;
}

img.inline {
    max-width: 1.5em;
    max-height: 1.5em;
    margin: -0.25em;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.text-word {
    color: white;
}

.text-word.massive {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.text-word.large {
    font-weight: 300;
}

.text-word.error {
    margin-left: -5px;
}

.text-word.four-zero-four {
    color: #90B774;
}

.button-div {}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background: #586067;
    margin: 0 0.75em 0.25em 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.button:hover {
    background: #3c444b;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.button:active {
    background: #607352;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}


.block-level-div {
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Error 404</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/404.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="svg-background">
    <svg class='main-bg' viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 55,100 100,0" style="fill: rgba(29, 37, 44, 0.9);" class="large-only" />
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 80,100 100,0" style="fill: rgba(29, 37, 44, 0.9);" class="small-only" />
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 100,100 100,0" style="fill: rgba(29, 37, 44, 0.9);;" class="tiny-only" />
    </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="text-container-parent">
            <div class="text-container">
            <div style="margin: auto" class="block-level-div">
                <div class="logo-and-title no-select block-level-div">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" class="no-select logo-large" />
                <div class="title-row block-level-div">
                    <span class="text-word massive error">ERROR </span>
                    <span class="text-word massive four-zero-four">404</span>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-word large no-select block-level-div">OOPS...Looks like you may have taken a wrong turn.</div>
                <div class="text-word large no-select block-level-div">Don't worry, it happens to the best of us.</div>
                <div class="button-div no-select-buttons block-level-div">
                    <a href="https://google.com.com/" class="button">Take Me Home! <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" class="inline" /></a>
                    <a href="mailto:me@google.com" class="button">Report A Problem</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hide the scrollbars in Internet Explorer, all you have to do is add `overflow-y: hidden` to `body`:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,700');
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #F1F1F1 url('http://via.placeholder.com/1900');
  background-size: cover;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.main-bg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -9999;
}

.main-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 500px;
}

.large-only,
.small-only,
.tiny-only {
  display: none;
}

.text-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text-container-parent {
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  .large-only {
    display: block;
  }
  .text-container-parent {
    width: 55%;
  }
  .text-container {
    padding-bottom: 8vh;
  }
  .text-word.massive {
    font-size: 5.2vw;
    letter-spacing: -5px;
  }
  body {
    font-size: 1.68vw;
  }
  .button-div {
    padding-top: 2.6vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 721px) and (max-width: 1279px) {
  .small-only {
    display: block;
  }
  .text-container-parent {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .text-word.massive {
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    font-size: 7vw;
  }
  body {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
  }
  .button-div {
    padding-top: 3.5vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .tiny-only {
    display: block;
  }
  .text-container-parent {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .text-word.massive {
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    font-size: 12.2vw;
  }
  body {
    font-size: 3.5vw;
  }
  .button-div {
    padding-top: 6.1vw;
  }
  .text-container {
    position: static;
    transform: none!important;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 2em;
  }
  .title-row {
    margin: auto;
  }
  .button-div {
    margin: auto;
  }
  .logo-and-title {
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .main-container {
    height: 100%!important;
    width: 100%!important;
    margin: auto!important;
    min-width: inherit!important;
  }
  body {
    background: #F1F1F1;
  }
  .main-bg {
    min-width: inherit!important;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.text-container-parent {
  height: 100%;
}

.no-select {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.no-select-buttons {
  user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

img.logo-large {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 32vh;
  max-height: 32vh;
  text-align: center;
}

img.inline {
  max-width: 1.5em;
  max-height: 1.5em;
  margin: -0.25em;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.text-word {
  color: white;
}

.text-word.massive {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.text-word.large {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.text-word.error {
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.text-word.four-zero-four {
  color: #90B774;
}

.button-div {}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: #586067;
  margin: 0 0.75em 0.25em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #3c444b;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.button:active {
  background: #607352;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.block-level-div {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Error 404</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/404.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="svg-background">
      <svg class='main-bg' viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 55,100 100,0" style="fill: rgba(29, 37, 44, 0.9);" class="large-only" />
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 80,100 100,0" style="fill: rgba(29, 37, 44, 0.9);" class="small-only" />
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 100,100 100,0" style="fill: rgba(29, 37, 44, 0.9);;" class="tiny-only" />
    </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="text-container-parent">
      <div class="text-container">
        <div style="margin: auto" class="block-level-div">
          <div class="logo-and-title no-select block-level-div">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" class="no-select logo-large" />
            <div class="title-row block-level-div">
              <span class="text-word massive error">ERROR </span>
              <span class="text-word massive four-zero-four">404</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-word large no-select block-level-div">OOPS...Looks like you may have taken a wrong turn.</div>
          <div class="text-word large no-select block-level-div">Don't worry, it happens to the best of us.</div>
          <div class="button-div no-select-buttons block-level-div">
            <a href="https://google.com.com/" class="button">Take Me Home! <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" class="inline" /></a>
            <a href="mailto:me@google.com" class="button">Report A Problem</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**However**, the actual 'root' of your problem is that you've set a `height` of `100%` on both `body` and `html`, in addition to adding a transformation to `.text-container` to compensate for this. I'd recommend removing this rule, and then modifying the padding of `.text-container` at certain widths:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  .text-container {
    padding-top: 5%;
  }
}
```

This can be seen in the following:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,700');
body,
html {
  /*height: 100%;*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #F1F1F1 url('http://via.placeholder.com/1900');
  background-size: cover;
}

.main-bg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -9999;
}

.main-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 500px;
}

.large-only,
.small-only,
.tiny-only {
  display: none;
}

.text-container {
  /*
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  */
}

.text-container-parent {
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  .text-container {
    padding-top: 5%;
  }
  .large-only {
    display: block;
  }
  .text-container-parent {
    width: 55%;
  }
  .text-container {
    padding-bottom: 8vh;
  }
  .text-word.massive {
    font-size: 5.2vw;
    letter-spacing: -5px;
  }
  body {
    font-size: 1.68vw;
  }
  .button-div {
    padding-top: 2.6vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 721px) and (max-width: 1279px) {
  .small-only {
    display: block;
  }
  .text-container-parent {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .text-word.massive {
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    font-size: 7vw;
  }
  body {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
  }
  .button-div {
    padding-top: 3.5vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .tiny-only {
    display: block;
  }
  .text-container-parent {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .text-word.massive {
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    font-size: 12.2vw;
  }
  body {
    font-size: 3.5vw;
  }
  .button-div {
    padding-top: 6.1vw;
  }
  .text-container {
    position: static;
    transform: none!important;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 2em;
  }
  .title-row {
    margin: auto;
  }
  .button-div {
    margin: auto;
  }
  .logo-and-title {
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .main-container {
    height: 100%!important;
    width: 100%!important;
    margin: auto!important;
    min-width: inherit!important;
  }
  body {
    background: #F1F1F1;
  }
  .main-bg {
    min-width: inherit!important;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.text-container-parent {
  height: 100%;
}

.no-select {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.no-select-buttons {
  user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

img.logo-large {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 32vh;
  max-height: 32vh;
  text-align: center;
}

img.inline {
  max-width: 1.5em;
  max-height: 1.5em;
  margin: -0.25em;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.text-word {
  color: white;
}

.text-word.massive {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.text-word.large {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.text-word.error {
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.text-word.four-zero-four {
  color: #90B774;
}

.button-div {}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: #586067;
  margin: 0 0.75em 0.25em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #3c444b;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.button:active {
  background: #607352;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.block-level-div {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Error 404</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/404.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="svg-background">
      <svg class='main-bg' viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 55,100 100,0" style="fill: rgba(29, 37, 44, 0.9);" class="large-only" />
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 80,100 100,0" style="fill: rgba(29, 37, 44, 0.9);" class="small-only" />
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 100,100 100,0" style="fill: rgba(29, 37, 44, 0.9);;" class="tiny-only" />
    </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="text-container-parent">
      <div class="text-container">
        <div style="margin: auto" class="block-level-div">
          <div class="logo-and-title no-select block-level-div">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" class="no-select logo-large" />
            <div class="title-row block-level-div">
              <span class="text-word massive error">ERROR </span>
              <span class="text-word massive four-zero-four">404</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-word large no-select block-level-div">OOPS...Looks like you may have taken a wrong turn.</div>
          <div class="text-word large no-select block-level-div">Don't worry, it happens to the best of us.</div>
          <div class="button-div no-select-buttons block-level-div">
            <a href="https://google.com.com/" class="button">Take Me Home! <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" class="inline" /></a>
            <a href="mailto:me@google.com" class="button">Report A Problem</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I love yours as well! :D
Though, my intention isn't to hide the overflowing content, but prevent content which is randomly overflowing. 
Because if the page actually required vertical overflow (landscape oriented mobile devices), it would be hidden.

Comment: Well the problem is that you're setting a `height` of `100%` on both `body` and `html`, and then offsetting this by using a transformed `.text-container`. I'd recommend taking this rule off (your layout will still be full page due to `background-size: cover`), and then adjusting the text itself. `overflow-y` hidden is a quickfix, and if necessary, you can always allow inner elements to overflow again by making use of a `clearfix` instead :)

Comment: Thanks Dash! That sounds like it will work. 
Oh how I do /love/ IE and its weird idiosyncrasies.